# memory problem when saving images with UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiimage

My app makes use of lots of scaled images in animations.  To avoid skipping frames, I scale my images and save them, before running the animation.  Here is my code to save images:

```
+ (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)name {
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data attributes:nil];

}
```

Unfortunately, when I call this function repeatedly, I have memory problems.  I guess I'm trying to save about 10MB worth of images.  I'm thinking that perhaps the problem is with the autoreleased variables--perhaps I should alloc the data, and release at the end.  But I can't find an alloc version of `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Having received v. nice answers from @occulus and @Tommy wrt. autoreleased vars--that nevertheless did not seem to solve the problem, I wonder if something else can be the cause!?

Comment: I think I understand the problem now.  I need to have an autorelease pool when I _scale_ the images, as well as when I save them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the outer loop look like? If it's something like:

```
for(n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
{
    ... something ...
    [class saveImage:image withName:name];
}
```

Then leaving things in the autorelease pool could be your problem. The autorelease pool is drained only when the call stack completely unwinds back to the run loop (since otherwise you wouldn't be able to use autoreleased things as return results). Given that you're not releasing anything, you might try modifying your code to:

```
+ (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)name {
    // create a local autorelease pool; this one will retain objects only
    // until we drain it
    NSAutoreleasePool *localPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data attributes:nil];

    // drain the pool, which acts like release in reference counted environments
    // but also has an effect in garbage collected environments
    [localPool drain];
}
```

So, for each save of the image you create your own autorelease pool. The most recently initialised autorelease pool automatically sets itself to catch all autoreleased objects from then on. In a garbage collected environment like iOS, calling 'drain' on it causes it to be deallocated and all objects it holds instantly to be released.

Comment: Hey, thanks @Tommy.  I just tried this, but got a "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”." error straight away.  I think there may be a problem releasing the data, and the associated image!?

Comment: OK, compiled and ran this again, with no changes, and it worked fine this time

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this on the device right now, because I get this insane "Couldn't register ... with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”." error.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate; probably the first thing to do is a static analysis to see if there are any memory management errors it can spot for you, then do a debug build and run with the debugger attached to find out where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs. That'll almost certainly be an attempt to access an object you've deallocated. EDIT: rebooting the device would probably solve the remote debugging problem.

Comment: OK, sorted that, tested on device.  This seems to help a bit, but I still get an error when I increase the number of images I'm saving.

Comment: Then it's probably worth approaching the problem empirically. Use Instruments, particularly the allocations and leaks tools, and see what sort of objects you're spending your memory on and whether you're leaking any of them.

Comment: @Tommy, thanks for your helpful suggestions.  Rebooting did work.  Whenever I try to run with instruments I get "Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”.", and in instruments, "iOS Simulator failed to find the process ID of ...".  It is working (with limited images) otherwise. :-(

Comment: OK, scratch that.  Instruments works when I debug on the device, rather than the simulator.  Still, didn't get anything useful from it.  In one place, I was doing a UIColor alloc, which was a small leak.  Elsewhere, it thought an NSLog(@"..."); was a leak!?  Nothing in my image saving loop.

Answer (score 4):

UIImagePNGRepresentation returns an autoreleased NSData object. In other words, the data allocated will only be dealloced once you get to the release (or drain) call of the nearest enclosing NSAutoreleasePool block.

If you are calling the above code from within a loop, it's possible your code is never getting the chance to autorelease all that memory. In this sort of situation, you can enclose your calls in your own NSAutoreleasePool:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [self saveImage:someImage withName:@"someName.png"]; 

    [pool drain];
}
```

N.B. I believe working with PNGs this way is quite slow compared to using JPGs (UIImageJPGRepresentation). Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your quick answer! I will try that.  I'm working with PNGs, partly because I need a transparency component, partly because I understand that iPhones 'like' PNGs.